# Xcode won't run or step into one of my called methods

Tags: xcode, function, call

I'm not sure what's expected for me to leave here, but basically, I've passed an object of type AwesomeMenu into an ActionControl object's (subclass of NSOBject) initializer class so that the ActionControl object has a reference to the AwesomeMenu. However, in one of the ActionControl functions, there is a call like

```
[self.menu updateButton];
```

Where self.menu is the AwesomeMenu and updateButton is a function within AwesomeMenu. For some reason, XCode never enters updateButton. I've tried setting up breakpoints inside updateButton. They don't ever trip. I tried stepping INTO updateButton (it just shows me the parameters and then it skips past the line without taking me into the function), etc. I don't get any errors either. My chosen path through the program takes me over that function call multiple times but it never actually calls.

What's happening?

Comment: Are you sure `self.menu != nil`?

Comment: when it steps over it (you try to step in but it jumps over it) what is the value of `self.menu` I bet it is nil.

Comment: AGh! Big amateur mistake. You guys were right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not assign self.menu prior to calling one of its functions; self.menu's value was nil. I just had to switch my initialization statements around to get it to work.